# Python type annotation for custom duck type

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting, duck-typing

Python's `typing` module defines a number of duck types, e.g., `typing.SupportsAbs` to represent any type that implements the `__abs__` special method.

Is it possible to define custom duck types in a way such that I can use them as valid type annotations?

For example, I would like to be able to annotate that an argument should be a duck-type equivalent of a `threading.Lock`, i.e., any object that implements `acquire` and `release` methods. Ideally, I could annotate such an argument as `SupportsAcquireAndRequire` or `DuckLock`, rather than `object`.

Comment: Have you looked at how they're defined? You could do something similar pretty easily.

Comment: Indeed, `SupportsAbs` is only a few lines of code inheriting from the private `typing._Protocol`. Is there a way to do this that doesn't involve using private API?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can define an [abstract base class (ABC)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html) to specify the interface:

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod

class SupportsAcquireAndRequire(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    @abstractmethod
    def acquire(self):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def release(self):
        pass

    @classmethod
    def __subclasshook__(cls, C):
        for method in ('release', 'acquire'):
            for B in C.__mro__:
                if method in B.__dict__:
                    if B.__dict__[method] is None:
                        return NotImplemented
                    break
            else:
                return NotImplemented
        return True
```

This is basically how the protocols (like `typing.SupportsAbs`) are implemented, albeit without directly using `ABCMeta`.

By giving the ABC a [`__subclasshook__` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html#abc.ABCMeta.__subclasshook__), you can use it in `isinstance()` and `issubclass()` tests, which is more than good enough for tools like [`mypy`](http://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/class_basics.html?highlight=abc#abstract-base-classes-and-multiple-inheritance):

```
>>> from threading import Lock
>>> isinstance(Lock(), SupportsAcquireAndRequire)
True
```

Comment: Looks like this is about the best we can do for now -- this is actually still an open issue for `typing`: https://github.com/python/typing/issues/11

Comment: @shoyer: yes, which is why the mypy documentation I linked to mentions that more explicit support for duck-typing is still forthcoming. Until then, ABCMeta is the way to go.

Comment: Any idea why we do not check the method *signatures* at runtime but only the method *names* (in the `__subclasshook__` implemented in `collections.abc` and `typing`)? It makes the dynamic view (partial type checking) inconsistent with the static view (full type checking) of structural subtyping.

Comment: @Maggyero it is consistent with the way ABCs work, they only ever enforce names.

Comment: @MartijnPieters +1 You are right. First [`abc.ABCMeta`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.10.3/Lib/_py_abc.py#L37-L46) sets an `__abstractmethods__` attribute on its instances to a `frozenset` of method names which have an `__isabstractmethod__` attribute set to `True`. Then [`object.__new__`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.10.3/Objects/typeobject.c#L4467-L4498) checks that the `abc.ABCMeta` instances have no `__abstractmethods__` attribute set to a non-empty iterable of `str` when they are themselves instantiated since only non-abstract classes can be instantiated.

Answer (score 8):

`typing` has updated to support use-cases like this one - you may use [`typing.Protocol`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Protocol) for this.

```
from typing import Protocol, runtime_checkable

@runtime_checkable
class LockLike(Protocol):
    def acquire(self) -> None:
        ...

    def release(self) -> None:
        ...
```

You need [`@runtimecheckable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.runtime_checkable) if you want to be able to use `isinstance` as in Martijn's answer.

```
>>> from threading import Lock
>>> isinstance(Lock(), RuntimeCheckable)
True
```